# Finder opens new window each time

Tags: macos, finder, dmg

I just created a DMG and threw some folders in it. If I double-click a folder it opens in a new Finder window each time. Folders outside of the DMG are still opening normally. Holding `option` when I double-click causes the former window to close, but it's pretty inconvenient. Does anyone know how to get a DMG to show up in a normal Finder shell?

This is what I'm seeing, for what it's worth:

[image]

Comment: I hope someone has a hidden preference to enable this since the Finder and [DiskImageMounter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DiskImageMounter) clearly want to make a new window when it first mounts a dmg. I poked a bit at `hdiutil imageinfo file.dmg` on several images to see if there were a field that could be set to suppress this, but nothing looks promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many things that could be going wrong here. First of all, make sure that when you navigate to Finder > Preferences > General, the option "Always open folders in a new window" is unchecked. If not, there are many solutions to your problem listed below:

- Naviate to View > Show Toolbar
- Navigate to View > as List, as Columns, or as Cover Flow
- Get TotalFinder (http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/), which adds many more settings to Finder

Good luck!